# Batch pause not working

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, for-loop

I'm trying to figure out why pause not work with this code, anybody can help me?

```
   @echo off

    for %%1 in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
        if exist %%1:\ (
        set d=%%1:
        call :processToken
        )
      )
    goto :eof

    :processToken
    for /f "tokens=1-5*" %%1 in ('vol %d%') do (
       set vol=%%6 & goto done
    )
    :done
    echo %d% name=%vol%
    goto :eof

    pause
```

Comment: [Off topic]: I suggest you to NOT use numbers in the `for` replaceable parameter! Altough they works, may lead to confusions with the Batch file parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because it is never reached.

You have a `goto :eof` the line before, which stopps the batch.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

(note the replacement of the :EOF label to :EndOfFile which will call the pause function everytime)

@echo off

```
for %%1 in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
    if exist %%1:\ (
    set d=%%1:
    call :processToken
    )
  )
goto :EndoOfFile

:processToken
for /f "tokens=1-5*" %%1 in ('vol %d%') do (
   set vol=%%6 & goto done
)
:done
echo %d% name=%vol%
goto :EndoOfFile

:EndoOfFile
pause
```